# Why i cannot delete data in phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

[image: This is my data in table]

I just want to delete one record from this table. So, i click delete button but it show this error.

[image]

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Version information is usually listed on the main page, in the boxes to the far right.

Answer (score 1):

You specified a WHERE statement, but you didn't execute any term. Either remove the WHERE statement (which deletes a random item from the table (thanks @DanFromGermany) or add the term

if you clicked on the delete link, try to check the row before

Comment: If he uses no `WHERE` statement but keeps the `LIMIT 1`, a single (more or less) random row gets deleted.

Comment: @Marco 
But i didn't manual the code to delete it. I just click delete link. i didn't specified WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause for this behaviour is when you fire a query that does not include a primary key in the output. phpMyAdmin then does not know which column identifies a selected row.

Can you verify this?

Another thing is, your phpMyAdmin looks outdated, can you try the same thing with an up to date version?